# How can I make this visual resource scheduling effect (like this picture) using JQuery and/or JQuery Plugins?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I need to visually represent multiple resources (vertically) and the time of the day (horizontally) as shown in this mockup:

[image]

I need to be able to drag and drop the colored boxes into different available time slots.

I also need to be able to display text in the boxes.

We are using JQuery already (and [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)) for a lot of other scheduling functionality in our website.

How can I make this effect with a JQuery PlugIn or JQuery itself?

Comment: That is a very broad questions.  Perhaps break this down into more modular tasks and seek assistance with those?

Comment: I woudld recomend a deep study on all the possibilities, there must be a more viable sollution that doing the way you're thinking of

Comment: I'm really just looking for a Plug In that looks like this.